# Edit & Update In Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, edit

While doing update i am getting following error

```
Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: user
```

This is my controller:

```
public function update_user_id($user_id) {

    if($this->input->post('submit')){
    $courses = array(

    'user_name'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
    'email'=>$this->input->post('email')
    );
    $this->users_model->update_user($user_id,$users);
    $base_url=base_url();
    redirect("$base_url"."Dashboard/update_user_id/$user_id");
    }
    $result['user']=$this->users_model->user_id($user_id);
    $this->load->view('edit_user',$result);
    }
```

Which is my view

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url().'Admin/update_user_id/'.$user[0]->user_id);?>  
 User Name: <input type="text" name="user_name" value=" <?php echo $user[0]->user_name;  ?>">
 Email: <input type="text" name="email" value=" <?php echo $user[0]->user_name;  ?>">
 <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Don't know whats wrong with the code

Comment: it looks like your update_course call in the method has 2 parameters and the function itself only takes 1.

Comment: so, then what the solution @SemicolonsandDuctTape

Comment: update_course($course_id,$courses) method does not exist in Coursesmodel

Comment: why do you have this line: $this->CoursesModel->update_course($course_id,$courses); instead of just $this->CoursesModel->update_course($course_id);

Comment: public function update_course($course_id,$courses){
          $this->db->where('course_id', $course_id);
          $this->db->update('courses', $courses);
    }

Comment: Show the code for CoursesModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always follow [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html). By CI council convention, your class names should follow file names. I suppose you have that right. But you didn't follow demand for [ucfirst()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) file and class names.

So in your case file shouldn't be named *CoursesModel* neither class should be named CoursesModel, but you should name your file and class **Coursesmodel**. Remember `ucfirst()` rule (regarding CI3+) for naming all classes wether controllers, models or libraries.

Also, if you load those files (models and libraries), for libraries always use [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) name while for models you can use both `strtolower()` and `ucfirst()` formatted name.

Personaly, I use to load libraries with strtolower while using to load models with ucfirst name and that way I make difference between those just having a quick look on code.

Try with:

**Courses_m.php** (This way I speed up parsing a little bit)

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('Not your cup of tea.');

class Courses_m extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function update_course($course_id, $courses)
    {
        // your DB task --should return something
        return true ?: false;
    }
}
```

And in controller:

**Courses_c.php** (in `APPPATH . 'config/routes.php'` you can set what ever name you like for your route)

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('Not your cup of tea.');

class Courses_c extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');//just an library loading example
        $this->load->model('Courses_m');//notice first capital here
    }

    public function update_course_id($course_id)
    {
        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            $courses = array(
                'course_name'=>$this->input->post('course_name'),
                'no_of_hours'=>$this->input->post('no_of_hours')
            );
            // pay attention on capital first when you calling a model method
            // need to be the same as in constructor where file is loaded
            $this->Courses_m->update_course($course_id,$courses);

            // you can use this way
            redirect(base_url("Dashboard/update_course_id/$course_id"));
        }
        // use else block to avoid unwanted behavior
        else
        {
            $result['course']=$this->Courses_m->course_id($course_id);
            $this->load->view('edit_course',$result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you can load model as `$this->load->model('courses_m');` and use it like `$this->courses_m->update_course($course_id,$courses);`. Thing you should remember is that is very important to have the same loaded and used name. Here, I just showed you how I use it. I am glad I could help.

Comment: hi @Tpojka i had a problem wih edit as undefined variable, so i have edited the previous quetion could you help me to fix

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Now, accepted answer wouldn't fit to question. Instead, revert back to previous state and ask new question.